# Loops and suspensions of higher categories

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Given a pointed $(\infty,n)$-category $\mathcal{C}$, one can define the suspension of $\mathcal{C}$, $\Sigma\mathcal{C}$, via the homotopy pushout of $$\ast\leftarrow \mathcal{C}\rightarrow \ast.$$ Dually one can define $\Omega\mathcal{C}$. Can one explicitly identify these $(\infty,n)$-categories in terms of $\mathcal{C}$?

My vague intuition, based on the case $n=0$, says that the $\Omega\mathcal{C}$ should be the endomorphisms of the distinguished object and $\Sigma\mathcal{C}$ should be what you get when you take the free monoidal $(\infty,n)$-category on $\mathcal{C}$, regard it as an $(\infty,n+1)$-category with one object and then invert the $n+1$-morphisms. However, my understanding of (homotopy) limits and colimits in this setting is pretty poor.

Feel free to use any model you wish.

Comment: If by "homotopy" you mean the usual notion then $\Omega C$ is the automorphisms, not the endomorphisms. Directed delooping in $n$-category theory with $n > (\infty,1)$ requires using "lax" generalizations of homotopy pullbacks, such as "comma objects" http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/comma+object

Comment: By homotopy pullback/pushout, I will take any construction that is equivalent to the derived pullback/pushout constructed using the projective/injective model structures on diagrams in a combinatorial model category modelling $(\infty,n)$-categories.

Comment: Do you have a proof that $\Omega\mathcal{C}$ is the automorphisms? In particular, why is it always an $(\infty,0)$-category?

Comment: $\Omega \mathcal{C}$ is the $(\infty,n)$-category of automorphisms not the space of automorphisms (i.e. objects are automorphisms but we allow arbitrary morphisms between them). The reason why these are not all endomorphisms is that $\Delta[1]$ is not an interval object but $E[1]$ (the nerve of the contractible groupoid with two objects) is (e.g. in the Joyal model structure or in the Rezk model structure for $\Theta_n$-spaces).

Comment: Karol, thanks for the clarification. I would guess that this would make the suspension similar to how I defined it, but we would also need to make all the objects in the free monoidal category invertible under the monoidal product before realizing it as a higher category.

Comment: @KarolSzumiło: So one way to take what you said and get your characterization of $\Omega\mathcal{C}$ is to say that if we glue two copies of $E[1]$ together along the discrete subcategory with two objects (and do this as pointed $(\infty,n)$-categories) we get a category which corepresents the loop functor.  I guess this category is supposed to be equivalent to the free $(\infty,n)$ category (in some sense) on the category with one object and one non-trivial automorphism? This intuitively makes sense. Do you have a model where this is easy to show?

Comment: Justin, I think it is quite evident in $\Theta_n$-spaces. You don't have to glue two copies of $E[1]$, you can just identify two objects to get (the nerve of) the group $\mathbb{Z}$. You can consider any category as a strict $n$-category and take its $\Theta_n$-nerve (which is a $\Theta_n$-set) and consider it as a discrete $\Theta_n$-space. That's a $\Theta_n$ model of your category seen as an $(\infty, n)$-category. In particular, if you do it to $\mathbb{Z}$ you obtain a $\Theta_n$-space $A$ such that maps $A \to \mathcal{C}$ classify automorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$...

Comment: ...basically by the definition of an equivalence in a $\Theta_n$-space.

Comment: BTW, I the case of suspensions might be more tricky. Of course you can use the interval $E[1]$ to compute $\Sigma \mathcal{C}$ but in order to understand what it "is" as an $(\infty,n)$-category you would probably have to replace it fibrantly (in the sense of whatever model you are using). It's not clear to me whether this is easily done.

Comment: @KarolSzumiło: The reason I glued two copies of $E[1]$ together is that I wanted a homotopy pushout that I could map out of to construct the homotopy pullback modeling $\Omega\mathcal{C}$. I need both a $(\infty,n)$ category that corepresents $Aut(1)$ and a presentation of that a category as a homotopy pushout which corepresents $\Omega$.

Comment: The pushout of $* \sqcup * \to E[1]$ and $* \sqcup * \to *$ is a homotopy pushout too since $* \sqcup * \to E[1]$ is a cofibration. However, I neglected the fact that the analogous pushout of categories is not preserved by the nerve functor. But that's even better, maps $E[1] \to \mathcal{C}$ classify equivalences in $\mathcal{C}$ by definition so maps $E[1] / (* \sqcup *) \to \mathcal{C}$ classify equivalences with the same source and target i.e. automorphisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let me thank Urs, Karol, and Rune Haugseng for helpful comments.

Now note that the inclusion, $i$, of $\infty$-groupoids into $(\infty,n)$-categories has an $\infty$-categorical left adjoint, $L$ (for lack of a better name), and a right adjoint $(-)^\prime$.

Given a pointed  $(\infty,n)$-category $\mathcal{C}$, the loop category $\Omega \mathcal{C}$ is defined by the following (homotopy) pullback diagram:

\begin{array}{ccc}
\Omega\mathcal{C} & \rightarrow & \ast\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\ast & \rightarrow & \mathcal{C}
\end{array}

Now $\mathcal{C}^{\prime}$ is the maximal sub-$\infty$-groupoid of $\mathcal{C}$ (the core). Since $\ast$ is an $\infty$-groupoid, the inclusion $\ast\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ factors canonically through $\mathcal{C}^\prime$. By a standard finality argument we see that $\Omega \mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to the homotopy pullback:
\begin{array}{ccc}
\Omega\mathcal{C} \simeq \Omega^{Top}\mathcal{C}^\prime& \rightarrow & \ast\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\ast & \rightarrow & \mathcal{C}^\prime
\end{array}

Regarding $\mathcal{C}^\prime$ as a space (since it is an $\infty$-groupoid), we see that $\Omega\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to the space of topological (based) loops on $\mathcal{C}^\prime$ since $i$ preserves (homotopy) limits.

Unraveling this a bit, we see that $\Omega(-)$ is naturally equivalent to $i\Omega^{Top}(-)^\prime$ which is a composite of right adjoints. It follows that the left adjoint, $\Sigma(-)$, is naturally equivalent to $i\Sigma^{Top}L(-)$.

As a consequence, an $(\infty,n)$-category which is a loop category is necessarily a loop space. This shows that the inclusion of spectra objects in $(\infty,0)$-categories (i.e., spectra) into spectra objects in $(\infty,n)$-categories is an equivalence. So the two categories have the same stailizations.

Comment: Could you say a bit more about the "standard finality argument"?

Comment: Oh I see: putting $C'$ instead of $C$ in the lower right corner simply doesn't change the universal property of the pullback in the $(\infty,1)$-category of $(\infty,n)$-categories.

Comment: Exactly, or one could check that the appropriate comma category is weakly contractible.